# Drop-down lists

Tags: feature-request, markdown

Would it be possible to have markdown drop-down lists in MO? I think that hiding lengthy examples, components of long proofs, edited out text etc., inside such menus could add readability.

Comment: These feature requests aren't the same, but they seem to be directed towards possibility to hide some part of text until needed: [Could we please have a clickable arrow to expand hidden content?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104008) and [Collapsible Sections/Spoilers](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/15432).

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yes, it seems that what is mentioned there could exactly be done with drop-down menus.

Comment: I remember an old MO question where answers to some quiz questions where hidden by using rot12 cypher, for lack of a hidden list option.

Comment: @YaakovBaruch, the ROT12 cipher has the advantage that you need only use it again 12 times to decode. 